# Laravel - Create User Registration Endpoint Based on User Group

Tags: angular, laravel, api

I am using Laravel 5.8 as my endpoint and Angular 7 as my frontend.

I have three tables: groups (model: Group), users (model: User) and users_group (model: UserGroup)

Group: id, group_name
User: id email, name, password
UserGroup: user_id, group_id

```
    public function returnResponse($success, $data, $errorCode = 0, $message = false) {
    $response = array();
    $response['success'] = $success;
    $response['message'] = isset($message) ? $message : '';
    if ($errorCode) {
        $response['errorCode'] = isset($errorCode) ? $errorCode : 0;
    }
    $response['data'] = $data;
    return response()->json($response, 200);
}


    public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users|max:255',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:8|max:20',
    ]);

    $user = new User();
    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    $user->save();         

    $success = array();
    $success['user_id'] = $user->id;
    $success['user']=$user;

    return $this->returnResponse(true, $success, 0, 'User registered successfully');                                       
}
```

route:
**api.php**

```
Route::post('register', 'ApiController@register');
```

I want to generate an endpoint from Laravel for for Angular.
A user can belong to more than one group. For a user to be created, you select the group, then the id of the group will be picked. The when you save the User Registration into the User Table, the user_id and the group_id will be saved into the UserGroup.

How do I modify my current codes above to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the group_id is sent on the request

```
    public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users|max:255',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:8|max:20',
    ]);

    $user = new User();
    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    $user->save();         

    UserGroup::create(['user_id' => $user->id, 'group_id' => $request->group_id]); 

    $success = array();
    $success['user_id'] = $user->id;
    $success['user']=$user;

    return $this->returnResponse(true, $success, 0, 'User registered successfully');                                       
}
```